# Struts2 tag with Math functions

Tags: java, struts2

I use struts2 and want to use Math.max method in struts tag .
Like this :

```
<s:property value="%{Math.max( 1 , 5 ) }" />
```

Or :

```
<s:set var="pfrom" value="%{Math.max( 1 , page - 5 )}" />
```

but this codes not work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the docs for [accessing static properties](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/ognl-basics.html#OGNLBasics-Accessingstaticproperties).

Nutshell: `%{@java.lang.Math@max(...)}`

You'll need to configure allowing static access in your Struts config file:

```
<constant name="struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess" value="true" />
```

I'd urge you to do work like that in the action, though, when possible. "Dumb" views are easier to test--the more logic in the controllers the easier things are all around.

The same logic could be exposed as an action method.

Answer (score 1):

Tags are always for presentation layer. Using them for any kind of mathematical or business logic defeats their purpose.

Mixing things up means you are not using the layered architecture the way it should be used.

It's better to perform such operations in action or utility classes as suggested by Dave. That said, you can go through the document as suggested in the post.